# What effect did the AWACS radar dome have on the stability of the 707?

Tags: aircraft-design

The large disc shape of the AWACS radar dome, and its attachment pylons to the fuselage, above and behind the wings, seem to have the potential to actually improve the pitch and yaw stability of the 707 carrier aircraft in spite of its ungainly appearance.

In light of the current debate over placement of increasingly large fan jet nacelles, could stability data from the AWACS radar dome configuration inspire improvements in current designs?

Comment: The nacelles suck in air at low speed, so the forces on their forward edges are much greater than those on an ellipsoid in free flow. Yes, the radome helps with directional and pitch stability but increases dihedral effect. However, given its large drag from the rounded trailing edge, nobody will seriously add a radome just to improve stability. Look at the Beech 1900 for ways to add some stability on the cheap. Hint: Place additional surfaces as far back as possible.

Comment: @Peter Kampf perhaps they will take another look at the Sonic Cruiser design, using fan jet nacelle area combined with horizontal stabilator area for improved stability.  For lower subsonic, bring the wing forward and straighten it out a bit.  They could turn the fan nacelle issue into a positive with a little bit more effort.  A triplane yes, but a good one.